Lipschitz sequence of functions in a star-shaped compact set
I did an Analysis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ course and in my professor's notes there was the following exercise, of which I was only able to the first question, and I could not do nor find the second question anywhere (from books to this site).
Question: Let K be a compact set which is star-shaped in respect to $0$, i.e., $\forall x(x \in K \implies tx \in K, \forall t \in [0, 1])$ and $(f_k)$ a sequence of functions such that $f_k: K \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to K$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $L_k \in [a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, in which $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ are arbitrary positive numbers.

Show that there exists some $f: K \to K$ Lipschitz to which a subsequence of $(f_n)$ converges uniformly.
Show that $f$ has a unique fixed-point in $K$.

I tried to imitate Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem to solve it, i.e., I tried to assume by contradiction that it has no fixed points and then try to make some kind of projection, but that led to nowhere, since I couldn't get a contradiction from none of them. I mean, it probably has to do with the fact that K is star-shaped in respect to $0$, but I can't seem how to use it. Do you have any ideas?

What does “unless of subsequences” mean?

Sorry, I think the translation was not good. It simply means that there is a subsequence of $(f_n)$ that converges uniformly to this such $f$.

Do you think Ascoli-Arzela theorem can be used?

I don't think so, because the theorem doesn't say anything about fixed-points.
